# How to perform has many on group by in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables,

`buyers`

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigint unsigned |
| name | varchar(255) |

`buyer_zips`

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigint unsigned |
| buyer_id | bigint unsigned |
| zip | varchar(255) |

A buyer can have multiple zips. `zip` in `buyer_zips` can be duplicate and hence a zip can have multiple buyers. My goal is to get the buyers that belongs to the zip. Example:

`buyers`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Company 1 |
| 2 | Company 2 |
| 3 | Company 3 |

`buyer_zips`

| id | buyer_id | zip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 90001 |
| 2 | 2 | 90001 |
| 3 | 3 | 90001 |
| 4 | 1 | 90002 |
| 5 | 2 | 90002 |

I want the end result to be something like,

```
[
  {
    "zip": "90001",
    "buyers": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Company 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Company 2"
      },

      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Company 3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "zip": "90002",
    "buyers": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Company 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Company 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I did the following,

```
BuyerZip::groupBy('zip_id')
    ->with('buyers')
    ->get();
```

And the relation,

```
// BuyerZip.php

public function buyers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Buyer::class, 'buyer_id', 'id');
}
```

How do I get all the buyers belonging to a zip?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, **a buyer can have multiple zips && hence a zip can have multiple buyers**. This not one-to-many relationship. That's really **many-to-many** relationship, so you need changing the Model and relationship and using Pivot Table.

Buyer Model:

```
use App\Models\Zip;
class Buyer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function zips() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Zip::class);
    }
}
```

Zip Model

```
use App\Models\Buyer;
class Zip extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function buyers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Buyer::Class);
    }
}
```

Pivot Table migration:

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('buyer_zip', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignid('buyer_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignid('zip_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('buyer_zip');
    }
};
```

You can then easily get Zip with related Buyers:

```
Zip::with('buyers')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `groupBy` in your builder. Leave it just like this:

```php
BuyerZip::with('buyers')->get()
```

Comment: I want the buyer zip to be grouped by zips. Please see the edited question for how I want the results to be.

Comment: Removing `groupBy` defeats the purpose.

Comment: have you try it?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstand. Why don't you create a separate zips table and define the relation as many-to-many instead?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
BuyerZip::with('buyers')->groupBy('buyer_id')->all()
```